# Thrift Java TNonBlockingServer hangs randomly

Tags: java, c, thrift

I have a Thrift server implemented in Java like the following:

```
TNonblockingServerTransport serverTransport = new TNonblockingServerSocket(getThriftPort(), 100);

TServer tserver = new TNonblockingServer(new TNonblockingServer.Args(serverTransport).processor(processor)
                    .inputProtocolFactory(new TBinaryProtocol.Factory())
                    .outputProtocolFactory(new TBinaryProtocol.Factory())
                    .transportFactory(new TFramedTransport.Factory()));
```

And my client is implemented in C. This server is primary used to serve bytes from the disk. The requests seem to be answered for a while before the server decides to hang randomly. Any tips on how I can debug this further?

After the process is stuck, if I run netstat, I see the data like the following:

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:9090            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      186002/java     
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:9090          127.0.0.1:51813             ESTABLISHED 186002/java     
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:51814         127.0.0.1:9090          ESTABLISHED 186210/client 
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:51813         127.0.0.1:9090          ESTABLISHED 186210/client 
tcp        1      0 127.0.0.1:52515         127.0.0.1:9090          CLOSE_WAIT  -               
tcp        1      0 127.0.0.1:52514         127.0.0.1:9090          CLOSE_WAIT  -               
tcp       51      0 127.0.0.1:9090          127.0.0.1:51814         ESTABLISHED -
```

Comment: do you reuse connection from C client or create new one each time ? After server been hang - can you check open connections ? something like   sudo netstat -anp | grep :<server_port> in *nix

Comment: attached the netstat data to the question. My java server is running on 9090. Earlier I was re-using the connections but just to rule out the stale connection issue, now I open/close connection every time. But in both cases I observe the server hang issue.

Answer (score 0):

I m going to close this issue since this may not be related to Thrift. Will add any details if I get it later.